# Undofile independent of the Vim version

Tags: vim, undo

I'm  using the Vim 7.3 feature `undofile` the following way:

```
if version >= 703
 set undofile
 set undodir=$HOME/.vim/undo
 set undolevels=1000
 set undoreload=10000
endif
```

I am using the same `.vimrc` and the same files (within a cloud storage) on different machines which do not support Vim 7.3 but use the old 7.2 version which does not support undofile out of box. Is there a solution for the 7.2 version compatible with the 7.3 undofile?

Comment: Your snippet will set all those options only in 7.3+ and not in older versions. It looks perfect to me. What exactly are you asking for? How to implement undofile in 7.2?

Comment: Yes and it would be perfect if the implementations where compatible.

Comment: Well, vim.org is where you are supposed to go if you want a plugin. Did you try it before asking here?

Comment: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3198 requires 7.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### version check

Because persistent undo was introduced with Vim 7.3, your version check is fine, and prevents errors in older Vims. Usually, you would check for the feature itself; `:help 'undofile'` has this note:

> ```
> {only when compiled with the |+persistent_undo| feature}
> ```

So the correct check (that also handles Vim 7.3 versions that were explicitly compiled without the feature) would be:

```
:if has('persistent_undo')
```

### persistent undo for Vim 7.2

The reason that persistent undo has been implemented in core Vim is that this would be very difficult or even impossible to do in a plugin. Therefore, I know of no plugin that back-ports this functionality to Vim 7.2; I also don't see any motivation for such an endeavor, because the feature is non-essential and the solution is so simple: just upgrade to the latest Vim. If you have to administrative rights to install Vim on the system, you could compile or copy a user-local installation of Vim into your home directory.

Comment: Thnaks for your answer. I tryed using a locally installed vim. But it is unstable and crashes from time to time. Seems like I have to investigate that further.